# What does this symbol ↑ mean?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Sorry for my bad english . I have a question about postfix expression , but i dont what symbol ↑ mean ? Thank for your help

Find the value of the postfix expression:
2 2 4 + 3 2 ↑ + 5 3 + * –

Comment: Although the specific symbol is usually the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knuth%27s_up-arrow_notation , it's much more likely to simply refer to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation here. So  "3 2 ↑" is *probably* supposed to mean "three to the power of two", or 3². With more context, one could be more sure (and probably write this as the most likely answer)

Comment: Thank for your help